# Simplify condition on loop

Tags: c, loops, refactoring

Have this loop statement

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if ((i == 4) || (i == 5) || (i == 7) || (i == 9))
        continue;
    /*some code */
}
```

I want to make more elegant this syntax:

```
if ((i == 4) || (i == 5) || (i == 7) || (i == 9))
```

Comment: The way it's written now seems pretty explicit about what it's doing.  Why are you looking to change it?

Comment: put a switch-case inside the loop, but your model is readable and explaining itself elegant enough

Comment: ^^^ what Kevin and Olaf say.  If it's clear, don't change it.

Comment: You can eliminate the `|| (i == 9)` term by switching the loop limit to `< 9`.

Comment: You should replace the if statement with if (i == (4|5|7|9))

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over the indices you want, a bit cumbersome but at least possible and makes it even more explicit:

```
const int indices[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 8 };

for(size_t j = 0; j < sizeof indices / sizeof *indices; ++j)
{
  const int i = indices[j];
  // Rest of your loop body here, i iterates over desired values.
}
```

This also removes the conditional. Very hard to say anything about the performance at this point of course. Those tests weren't free either.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'd go with mine. More `const`, proper looping.

Comment: @WeatherVane That was what "proper looping" referred to. But thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

I do not know the exact meaning of *elegant* here, but a cleaner and more maintainable approach is to use a *fall-through* `switch-case`, like

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    switch(i)
    {
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 7:
        case 9:
              continue;
      default:
               //otherewise
    }
}
```

In case, later you want to modify, it is easier to understand and maintain.

EDIT:

If you're working with a coding standard that does not allow *fall-through*, then, the current code is just fine. At most, if required, you can create an additional function to check for the *validity* of `i` and based on the true/false (0/1) return value, you can make the decision. The additional function will have the `if` check.

Comment: Some coding standards don't allow fall-through. The code in the question is fine to me.

Comment: @Olaf It's fine to me too, but in case we need to check for _more_ values, switch is a better approach IMHO. And standard does not restrict this. :)

Comment: The question does not mention that. Sometimes one should not think too far. Even if, there are possibly better ways, depending on a problem (e.g. test a bitmap).

Comment: @Olaf Appended the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, perhaps some bit-magic?

```
#define MAGIC_NUMBER 0x2B0 // binary  001010110000 with bits 4,5,7,9 set

...

if ( (MAGIC_NUMBER >> i) & 0x1)
    continue;
```

**Update:** The original code is just fine. This is presented just as an alternative if really required.

Comment: Elegant but hard to understand without a comment.

Comment: No.  Please no.  No magic unless magic is absolutely required.

Comment: Personally I would stick with the original code.. But I just came up with this trick and wanted to share :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// comment on WHY these numbers!!!
int values[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 8 };

for (i = 0; i < sizeof(values)/sizeof(values[0]); i++ )
{
    int value = values[i];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nice. But you should use `sizeof(values) / sizeof(values[0])` to get the number of elements in a non-char array.

Comment: Oops. Typing too fast

Comment: You can, and should, edit your answer to correct it (or consider deleting it yourself).  Otherwise, it will be downvoted and may be forcibly deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code looks fine as is, but if you're looking for something more aesthetically pleasing in the 'if' conditional you could do:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
  if(foo(i)){
        continue;
       /*some code */
  }
}

int foo(int i){
    return ((i == 4) || (i == 5) || (i == 7) || (i == 9));
}
```

Comment: You know that logical operators can return true/false, right? No explicit `if` check required. And I don't really see any improvement here..

Comment: `public boolean` is not C and this solution is basically the same as the OP's except that `if(foo(i))` is not really understandable.

Comment: I'll downvote this answer if it doesn't disappear or if it will not be improved.

Comment: The question seemed to be a matter of programming aesthetics. Therefore, whether or not you see my answer as an improvement is subjective. I personally saw no problem with the way OP wrote his/her code but was simply providing an alternative approach. As for the errors I apologize. I did not notice the question was C-specific. Furthermore, 'foo' was just a placeholder. OP could rename the function to be as descriptive as his/her heart desires.

Answer (score -1):

Kinda surprised that no one has stated the obvious solution yet...

Anyway, What I would do in your situation is replace your loop:

```
if ((i == 4) || (i == 5) || (i == 7) || (i == 9))
    continue;
/*some code */
```

with

```
if (i == (4|5|7|9)) {
    continue;
/* some code */
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does.  The 4 bit, 1 bit, 2 bit and 8 bit all get set when you or them together, leaving a comparison to 15... not the desired results.